# Server Specs for browser game that hugs cpu

Tags: nginx, performance, php-fpm, load-testing

Our team have developed a web browser game, our servers are using nginx and php-fpm to host the website. the game consist of two parts an api and the game itself. both applications reside on its own server. during load testing I found out that both applications spawn many php-fpm threads making the cpu usage of both servers reach 100%, during the analysis we have found out that these cpu hugs are due to complex sql queries. What can we do to speed up our servers response time?

Comment: Fix the queries?

Comment: queries are all using indexes and already optimized, but the profiler still shows that the queries take time

Comment: There's not nearly enough information here to begin to answer.

Comment: Suggest you post on Stack Exchange DBA site for help with your database issues, it's a specialized topic. SF is more for server stuff than DBA stuff. http://dba.stackexchange.com/